# Coefficient in expansion - Discrete Math

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $\alpha$ be the coefficient of $x^2y^2z^2$ in $ (x^2+3y-2z)^5$. Show that $800\leq|\alpha|<1100$.

By my calculation, $\alpha=\binom {5}{2} \times (3^{2})\binom {3}{2} \times(-2)^2 \binom {1}{2}$

However $\binom {1}{2}=0$, so $\alpha$ should be $0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see here $$x^{10}+15 x^8 y-10 x^8 z+90 x^6 y^2-120 x^6 y z+40 x^6 z^2+270 x^4 y^3-540 x^4 y^2 z+360 x^4
   y z^2-80 x^4 z^3+405 x^2 y^4-1080 x^2 y^3 z+1080 x^2 y^2 z^2-480 x^2 y z^3+80 x^2 z^4+243
   y^5-810 y^4 z+1080 y^3 z^2-720 y^2 z^3+240 y z^4-32 z^5$$

Comment: It's a waste of computational time and effort to compute this. Your method is very sloppy and inefficient to get a simple answer.

Comment: just use multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
1^1\cdot3^2\cdot(-2)^2\cdot\overbrace{\binom{5}{2,2}}^{\substack{\text{trinomial}\\\text{coefficient}}}
&=1^1\cdot3^2\cdot(-2)^2\cdot\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}\\
&=1080
\end{align}
$$

Comment: [Trinomial Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion)

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $x^2$ in $$(x^2+3y-2z)^5$$ will be $$\binom51(3y-2z)^4$$

Now the  coefficient of $y^2z^2$ in$$(3y-2z)^4$$  will be $$\binom423^{4-2}(-2)^2$$

Comment: (+1) $\binom{5}{2,2}=\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{2}$